How can i mock knex transaction
i have unit test for function sync in these code but i get error like below i cant mock the function knex.transaction() for trx. i have tried some another way but i usually get trx is not the fuction im know im just a newbie with this please help me
const { knex } = require('../../../models')

const sync = async (req, acc) => {
    debug('sync')

    const trx = await knex.transaction()

    try {
        const [bookingId] = await trx('booking').insert(booking, ['id'])

        await trx('booking_pax').insert(bookingPaxes)

        await trx.commit()

        return res //from the line i deleted
    } catch (ex) {
        await trx.rollback()
        throw ex
    }
}
module.exports = {
    sync,
}

here is the model.js
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql2',
    connection: config.mariadbUrl
})
module.exports = {
    knex,
}

in my unit test file
const { knex } = require('../../../../models');
jest.mock('../../../../models',() => ({
    knex: {
        transaction: jest.fn()
    }
}));
describe('sync', () => {
let trx;
beforeEach(() => {
         trx = {
            insert: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
            commit: jest.fn(),
            rollback: jest.fn()
        };

        // Mock implementation of knex.transaction
        knex.transaction.mockImplementation((cb) => {
            return cb(trxMock)
                .then(() => trxMock)
                .catch((err) => { throw err; });
        });
    });
it('should successfully sync booking and paxes', async () => {
        trx.insert.mockResolvedValueOnce([1]);


       

        const result = await sync(req, acc);

        expect...
    });
});




i got error like this i think because i mock wroong way
 Expected substring: "Insert error"
    Received message:   "cb is not a function"

          131 |         // Mock implementation of knex.transaction
          132 |         knex.transaction.mockImplementation((cb) => {
        > 133 |             return cb(trxMock)
              |                    ^
          134 |                 .then(() => trxMock)
          135 |                 .catch((err) => { throw err; });
          136 |         });

can someone help me for mock knex.transaction()
